# How to create foreign key with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, foreign-keys

I started to learn Doctrine and trying to create a relationship between two columns with a foreign key. In my example the relationship should be implemented inside one table. Here is my `Entity` class:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BranchRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "tst_branches")]
class Branch
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(
        targetEntity: Branch::class,
        inversedBy: 'id'
    )]
    private int $parent_id;
}
```

Then I'm creating the database structure with:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

As a result I see two columns as expected but there is no foreign key to link `parent_id` and `id` columns.

[image]

What should be changed to create a foreign key in the database structure?

The expected result should looks as following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create this structure the following things should be fixed:

- Think about properties like about data objects, not like table columns in the database. Describe data relations and Doctrine will create the needed database structure.
- In this case, the relationship should be described in both directions (`OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`)
- The `ManyToOne` should describe a relational object, not the column. Doctrine will create the needed column automatically
- It is enough to use `$parent` name instead of `$parent_id`. Doctrine will add the `_id` suffix automatically. In case if the related column is not `id`, describe it as `ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'parent_id', referencedColumnName: 'root_id')`

The final result is:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BranchRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "tst_branches")]
class Branch
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(
        targetEntity: Branch::class,
        mappedBy: 'parent'
    )]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(
        targetEntity: Branch::class,
        inversedBy: 'id'
    )]
    private Branch|null $parent;
}
```